# Notebook throws KeyError on colab but loops infinitely on VScode

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have written a code for a dataset class and a data loader and there is a KeyError that I am aware of and trying to debug.

The issue is when I try to run this code on my local VScode environment instead of throwing a KeyError like it should it just loops infinitely and trying to interrupt the cell does not work and I have to restart the entire notebook.`

```
dataset_train = COCO_Features(
    _df=train_ids,
    _vocab=train_vocab,
    _features=features_map,
)

dataloader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True,          num_workers=4, collate_fn=caption_collate_fn)
```

The error should be on this statement

```
next(iter(dataloader_train)).shape
```

I wanted to know if anyone has experienced this and knows how to solve this. Only posting the snippet with the error as the original notebook too big to post and I believe irrelevant to the actual issue.

I tried looking at all the different extensions I have installed but nothing seems to be out of the ordinary just the pylance and python extension by microsoft are installed.

Comment: debug the code OUTSIDE a notebook

Comment: That's what I am currently forced to do, but it is not optimal and would like to fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, it seems to be due to the num_workers option. Setting it to zero made it work.

```
dataloader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, collate_fn=caption_collate_fn)
```

For some reason, VScode cannot spawn a new process properly on Windows but does not throw any error.